# Dictionary that holds Blocking Collections of different Type without casting

Tags: c#, collections, types, interface, blockingcollection

Can I setup a Dictionary of `MyDict<Type, BlockingCollection<"differentTypes">` possibly through an interface that circumvents any casting thus preventing the usage of object or dynamic types?

The reason I want to use such is because I want to initialize Blocking Collections of different types at runtime because incoming objects are of different types and I then want to add such incoming objects to the type matching Blocking Collection. I also want to access the objects within the BlockingCollection later on without having to cast. The necessary types of the Blocking collection are known at the instantiating time of the wrapping class. The types of the incoming object are known at runtime only. Incoming object types will never be different from the types known at the class instantiation time.  The types of the objects that I want to retrieve from the matching BlockingCollection are also only known at runtime. Any way to set this up without having to cast?

I browsed through many related questions but did not find the exact same specs described here.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid dynamic ?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but would it not add overhead because of possible boxing? Isn't it essentially an object type? of Utmost importance is latency and throughput and I try to void any sort of casting and boxing.

Comment: @Freddy what is the actual data here? what are the values?

Comment: @Marc, the values are class objects

Comment: @Freddy then why are you discussing boxing?

Comment: because I am a newbie ;-) Care to explain or point me to a link? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Lukas, I am actually standing corrected: I ran a sample using dynamics and it adds/takes several million objects to/from the blocking collection of type dynamic without too much overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, "differentTypes" means either `object`, or a common base-class / interface. If those types are value-types, then they will have to be boxed and unboxed (although you indicate that these are class objects so this doesn't apply - only `struct`s are ever boxed/unboxed). So that leaves a few casts - casts are pretty stonkingly fast: I wouldn't be too concerned about the impact of that.

Of course, if there is some commonality between the "differentTypes" (some common interface etc), then you might be able to use that common interface without ever casting.

Comment: Alright, so I essentially won't get around casting even when using interfaces?

Comment: @Freddy if using interfaces *properly*, there should be no need to cast

Comment: @Marc, how would I go about doing that? Given I pass in a List<Type> to the constructor of the enclosing class of the dictionary that holds BlockingCollections of different types would the type of the Dictionary be Dict<Type, IBlockingCollection>?

Comment: @Freddy you misunderstand me; it would need to be something like `Dict<Type, BlockingCollection<ISomeInterface>>`

Comment: @Freddy is there a question there? as a side note on stackoverflow itself, when writing anything involving generics, you need to be sure to use back-ticks (`\``) - otherwise things like `<` tend to disappear. So: if I write \`foo<t>\` it will come out as `foo<t>`

Comment: @Marc, I setup Dictionary<Type, BlockingCollection<ICollection>> buffers; ("ICollection being an empty interface") I add elements through buffers[typeof(T)].Add(message as ICollection); -> The only way I see to retrieve elements later on is through T receivedMsg = (T) buffers[typeof(T)].Take(). Isn't that the casting that I want to avoid? Any ideas what I am still doing wrong? Edit: Just saw your above comment. Is the code sample here legible?

Comment: @Freddy - if the type is known as collection, then is it possibly to just treat `receivedMsg` as `ICollection`? That is the point I'm making: you might not need to get it back to `T`. But! That ***really*** isn't an expensive operation.

Comment: @Marc, after pondering over couple ideas and your suggestions I decided to go with dynamic and casts. It was fast enough for my purpose. Note re the above, I needed to get back the objects as T. Thanks for your suggestions.